# android studio: type annotations are not supported

Tags: android, types

I simply referred to an already defined string, like this

Entry in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.res_learn:
            textview1settext(@string/str_learn);
            return true;
        case R.id.res_test:
            textview1settext(@string/str_test);
            return true;
        case R.id.res_result:
            textview1settext(@string/str_result);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And these references to strings causes at compilation time the error:

Error:(56, 35) error: type annotations are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable type annotations)

Now what? I actualized Android Studio within the last few weeks as proposed by the programm. As far as I understand these updates were no actualisation, I loaded down somewhat older.
Or has this error-message another reason. How do I fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

textview1settext(R.string.str_learn);

Btw just try to find some course about android development for beginners. 
For example on Coursera or Udacity.